# navigation bar is hidden when i return back to view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am new in iPhone development. I created an app which use a **navigation bar** using **storyboard**. My problem is that i am opening a **viewB** programmatically from viewA on button click and it successful. Now to go back to **viewA** i have used cancel button. when i click on cancel button (previous) the (**viewA**) is opened but navigation bar is not shown. and viewA have navigation bar control but **viewB** does not.

Thanks in advance

View A

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    EditViewController *viewController = (EditViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

View B:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ( lables != NULL) {

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        ScannerViewController *viewController = (ScannerViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ScannerViewController"];

        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:NULL];

    }
    else{

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: how you showing and closing the viewB? share your code if you need help.

Comment: From viewA are you presenting or pushing the viewB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are presenting the viewB & popping it using `self.navigationController`, you should use one way, either use presentviewcontroller & dismissviewcontroller.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

For your scenario it is best to use `UINavigationController`

e.g

**Pushing:**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

**Closing**

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a navigation controller, in your StoryBoard select your view A, Editor Menu > Embed In > Navigation controller.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard no need to present the viewController programmatically. press and hold ctrl, drag from `viewCA` to `viewCB` and select model from popup menu.

For dismissing the `viewController`

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to send any data to viewCB give segue identifier (for example "segid")

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segid"])
    {
        //write your code here.
    }
}
```

This method will get called automatically (`delegate`) while presenting (of pushing) `viewController`.

Comment: Thanks but i am programmatically add button to navigation bar. on navigation bar button click i open the viewB.

Comment: then also add button to navigation bar in storyboard. drag and drop the button in nav bar. press and hold ctrl + drag and drop from button  to the viewCB. follow as above. if you want create ibAction for that button and link it with the button.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. The solution is to never select the modal on click on the back button, because modal covers your whole view and that's why on the back screen navigation controller is not showing. So don't make connection for back button, just write the code for back button.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

When you needed (e.g. viewDidAppear method) use,

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: I do that using storyboard for particular viewController